# How does importing a module inside a function make code more modular?

Tags: python, oop, module, python-import, modular-design

From [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/all_together.html):

> You're used to seeing import statements at the top of a program, which
>   means that the imported module is available anywhere in the program.
>   But you can also import modules within a function, which means that
>   the imported module is only available within the function. If you have
>   a module that is only ever used in one function, this is an easy way
>   to make your code more modular.

The other alternative to importing module at the function level is to import it at the module level (of which the function is a part).

Since the module is the reusable unit, how does the former option increase modularity?

Comment: [Modular programming is a software design technique that emphasizes separating the functionality of a program into independent, interchangeable modules, such that each contains everything necessary to execute only one aspect of the desired functionality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)

Comment: And the [well-structured question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is?

Comment: @Kasramvd the other alternative to importing module at function level is to import it at the module level(of which the function is a part of) since module is the reusable unit, how does former option increase modularity?

Comment: Doing this is a violation of the guidelines in PEP 8.

Comment: Using imports only locally reduces coupling which indeed serves modularity, which is often defined as reducing intermodule coupling and enhancing intramodule cohesion. As far as PEP8 is concerned: It is a recommendation, not a dogma. Fortunately some relativating remarks are part of PEP8 itself.

Comment: Dive out of Dive Into Python.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't see what is wrong with the structure of the question. The title has the question and the body has the context. Repetition of the question again in the body doesn't make any sense. It only creates redundancy.

Comment: @q126y What is there that you don't understand about the quoted statement? Do you think it's correct? What form would an adequate answer take? Why are you not able to provide the answer yourself? What doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that importing at the function level is more modular. Importing a function (or class) from a module within Python will resolve the library dependencies, and those imported functions work without having to import the same libraries.

(Note: I'm using library to avoid saying module every other word)

Example:

my_module.py

```
import sys

def printerr(message):
    """Use stderr for error messages"""
    sys.stderr.write('{0}\n'.format(message))
    sys.stderr.flush()
```

my_script.py

```
import os

from my_module import printerr


def main():
    """Derpy script"""
    if 'my_important_file.txt' in os.listdir():
        print("it's there")
    else:
        printerr("ERROR: Unable to find important file")
```

Given, this is an extremely simplified example, but importing sys within printerr would not make it more modular. It's equally modular either way.

In my experience, the issues that can and do arise is related to tech-debt build up when it comes to modularity.

At first, you have a simple module with a well defined idea of what it does. The libraries imported within that module make sense and are highly used across the functions/classes within it.

As time goes on, and features are added, we often just add the new functions/classes in a "best fit" module (i.e. "I guess it makes sense to put that here?").

More time goes on, and a better library comes into popularity, so I'll use that one, but I really don't want to spend several weeks replacing all that old code (like I have that kind of time, I got things to make!).

Before long you have a gnarly bit of code that imports like 20 things and does way to much. And of course there are no unit tests, so every time you touch it, you break something, but it takes a week to find out...

Now you're sick of dealing with this, so screw it, I'll just import what I want within my functions that use it; this is easier than dealing with some 20 imports.

A very compelling reason to **not** import within functions is well demonstrated like this:

```
def doh():
    import nothing
    print "Homer says..."
```

That's a bug you just shipped, because doh never got called in your unit tests, but it gets called in this one weird way that you didn't think of. "If only I imported like PEP8 said, I wouldn't have this problem."